# How to get header tag element in afterrender event Ext JS?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

```js
var menuItem1 = new Ext.Panel({
   id: 'panelStart',
   title: 'Start',
   html: 'This is the start page.',
   cls:'menuItem',
   headerCfg: {
      tag: 'div',
      cls: 'title-part'              
      },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (comp) {
            var element = comp.getEl();
            element.on('click', function() {
                alert('ok')
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here we can easily access dom node of component but How to get div dom element of headerCfg inside an afterrender function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ExtJS 4+**

Panel header is instance of [Ext.panel.Header](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Header.html) class so you can simply use [`down()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html#method-down) method like this:

```
afterrender: function (panel) {
    var header = panel.down('header'),
        headerElement = header.getEl();
    headerElement.on('click', function () {
        alert('ok');
    });
}
```

Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bf4).

**ExtJS 3**

You can use [`header`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-property-header) property of the panel, like this `panel.header.getEl()`.

Comment: Didnt noticed ExtJS3 tag, for this version I believe you can use `comp.header.getEl()` - check this http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-property-header

Comment: got the header dom node using comp.header.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Novikov !